# How to write these equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to typeset these equations :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
We have
\[\tilde{P}_i^{1-\sigma}=\sum_j^N\left[\prod_{(Mji\succ0)}\tilde{p}_j^{1-\sigma}\theta_j\prod_{k=1}^Ke^{\beta_kD_{kji}}\right]\qquad\forall j\]
and
\[\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N\left[\mathrm M_{ij}-\exp(T_{ij}\overset{\smallfrown}{\delta})\right]T_{ij}=0\]
as well as
\[M_{ij}=\frac{Y_iY_j}{Y^W}\frac{\prod_{h=1}^He^{\delta_hD_{hji}}}{\tilde P_i^{1-\sigma}\tilde P_j^{1-\sigma}}\]
also
\[\prod_i^{1-\sigma}=\sum_{j}^N\left(\frac{t_{ij}}{\tilde P_j}\right)^{1-\sigma}\cdot\frac{E_j}{Y_t}\]

And these are inline:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\tilde{P}_i^{1-\sigma}=\sum_j^N\left[\prod_{(Mji\succ0)}\tilde{p}_j^{1-\sigma}\theta_j\prod_{k=1}^Ke^{\beta_kD_{kji}}\right]\qquad\forall j$
    \item $\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N\left[\mathrm M_{ij}-\exp(T_{ij}\overset{\smallfrown}{\delta})\right]T_{ij}=0$
    \item $M_{ij}=\frac{Y_iY_j}{Y^W}\frac{\prod_{h=1}^He^{\delta_hD_{hji}}}{\tilde P_i^{1-\sigma}\tilde P_j^{1-\sigma}}$
    \item $\prod_i^{1-\sigma}=\sum_{j}^N\left(\frac{t_{ij}}{\tilde P_j}\right)^{1-\sigma}\cdot\frac{E_j}{Y_t}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the OP's MWE was not there and now you've given the answer. LOL LOL.  :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Yeah! I had just had some fun so I could keep calm. Also it was in my free time ;-) But it is me who gave him the downvote.

Comment: @JouleV For me, the important thing is to help others. Obviously, if there's cunningness, then everything changes for me. Very good with the code you entered.